# Providing required formulae in mathematical statistics' final exam

Tags: mathematics, exams, statistics

In a final exam of mathematical statistics, a set of required statistical tables are allowed to be used. As a junior instructor of Mathematical Statistics, I want to know whether I can provide a sheet of some useful but huge formulae in the final exam. For instance, in the case of interval estimation there are some intervals for estimating difference between means,then can I provide them in final exam?

Comment: This is really dependent on your institution's culture and your role (what does 'junior instructor' mean?) and the amount of independence over the course you have been given.

Comment: by junior instructor I mean it is the first semester that I am teaching this course in this institution.

Comment: I don't see how anyone outside your institution could answer this in the way you'd need it to be answered (that is, for *you*, rather than for someone else or how they'd like it to be or even how it usually would be).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Over the years, my philosophy on exams has changed substantially and yours will probably too. My take on it is that I want to see student *understanding*, not *doing* or *memorization*. As a consequence, I no longer see value in students trying to remember complicated formulas (or indeed *applying* complicated formulas), and as a consequence my exam question sheets have often gotten quite long because they contain all of the relevant formulas as part of the question. Instead, they ask students to outline to me how a proof could work, or how one would decide between using formula (A) or (B) to assess whether a data set supports a hypothesis or not. This perspective is mostly driven by realizing that I want my students to be able to apply what they learned in the real world, where they can always look up the exact details of a formula, but where knowledge is pointless if there is no corresponding *understanding*. So I test understanding, not knowledge.

Applied to your situation, the question you should then ask yourself is not "is it *acceptable* to provide students with a collection of formulas?", but instead "what is it that I want my students to demonstrate?", and if you know what that is, you can ask yourself whether students need to *remember* formulas for that. If the remembering is not important to what you want students to demonstrate, then give them the formula.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with that in principle, but you need to discuss it first with the department head, especially since you hold a junior position. A tenured professor wouldn't need to clear it first, but you should.

An alternative, however, is to let students bring one sheet of paper, of a size you specify, on which they can write anything they like. Both sides. It might be as small as an index card. If you do that, you can initial them yourself so that students don't try to bring multiple sheets and switch them.

The advantage of this suggestion is that when the students provide their own "cheat sheets" they will have done some active learning to prepare them. The very preparation might make them redundant.

Comment: Yep, I often use that "cheat sheet" practice in my undergraduate courses too. When I was a student, one of our professors used to suggest that we make "shpargalki" (cheat sheets that would be easy to conceal and to read from on the exam) and then discard them: the process of creating a really efficient prop like that should make the product itself quite obsolete and if it doesn't, then "shpargalka" just wasn't good enough.

Comment: I once allowed the students (Calc 3) to bring a cheat sheet.  It was to be on one side of an 8 1/2 by 11 sheet of paper.  One kid cut his sheet into three strips and made a Möbius strip, thereby doubling the usable area.  He beat me fair and square.